# I have installed eventcalendar extension in civicrm

Tags: civievent, extension, calendar

I am following the steps provided in the Readme as given in the link below.

> Introduction
>   ------------ Event Calendar Extension allows you to view all CiviCRM events in a Calendar by month,day,week.The setting page allows us to
>   select which events should be shown on Calendar with the color we want
>   for particular event type.The setting page configuration for event
>   types filters allows us to filter by particular event types on
>   calendar.
>
> ### Installation
>
> 1. Move the downloaded extension to your extensions folder.
> 2. Goto civicrm/admin/extensions&reset=1  -- install the extension
>
> If you are new to CiviCRM Extension you can get help about extension
>   from
>
> http://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC42/Extensions
>
> Library
>   --------------- Extension uses the fullcalendar library. Add the fullcalendar library
>   https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/releases/tag/v1.6.7
>
> ### Usage
>
> 1. Click Administrator->CiviEvent->Event Calendar Settings menu (civicrm/eventCalendarsettings) -- change the setting if required.
> 2. Click Events->Show Events menu (civicrm/showevents) -- to view Event Calendar with Events as per settings.

https://github.com/osseed/com.osseed.eventcalendar

I have followed the installation steps #1 and #2 given below.
Also where should I add the fullcalendar library ?
In the Usage as mentioned, I don't see Administrator -> CiviEvent -> Event Calendar and also Events -> Show Events.
Kindly help me debug on what is wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

The fullcalendar is the plugin called "WP Calendar", if you have WordPress you install and activate it in the WordPress plugin area.

For the other issue, you may want to either disable/reinstall the civicrm extension, (works for some people), or take a look at answer to [How to use event calendar extension with civievents](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/22680/how-to-use-event-calendar-extension-with-civievents)

Also there is another step that you didn't list, to copy over the folder mentioned in the "Note" section of the README.